# Invalid address <0xF..F> passed to free: value not allocated; on std::string set

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I try to use a shared library.
This library needs to be compiled using standalone toolchain - so I did that.
But when I try to use one of the classes of the library I get this error:

```
A/libc: Invalid address 0x7f95fdb670 passed to free: value not allocated
```

at this line of code:

```
void setName(const std::string& name) { _name = name; }
```

I guess it tries to dispose _name and it's not allocated.
But in a debugger it shows that's name is empty string (_name="")

Any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: Most likely is that the function is being called on an invalid object.

Comment: Did you compile your application using the same toolchain that you used to build the library? If not, then there's no guarantee they'll be compatible. C++ does not define an ABI, so objects built with different compilers (or even different versions of the same compiler) are not guaranteed to be usable together in the same application.